# In SwiftUI, how can I position a NavigationLink a distance from the bottom

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

Example of similar code I am using:

```
struct SomScreen: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Image("SomeImage")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .padding()

            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: SomeNextScreen(), label: {
                    buttonToGetToNextScreen()
               })
           }
      }   
   }
}
```

My buttonToGetToNextScreen ends up in the middle of the VStack.   Is there a way to have if positioned from a distance from the bottom of the VStack?  Or if I remove the VStack, bottom of the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Spacer()` to push the content to the bottom of the VStack:

```
    struct SomScreen: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Image("SomeImage")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .padding()

            VStack {
                Spacer() // <--- Here
                NavigationLink(destination: SomeNextScreen(), label: {
                    buttonToGetToNextScreen()
               })
           }
      }   
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @nickreps 
[Documentation
/
SwiftUI
/
Layout fundamentals
/
Spacer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/spacer) describes the Spacer() method and how it can be used.